# I cant add Slingscold to plank1

Tags: plank

i add **Slingscold** but i cant see add it. **Slingscold.dockitem** *delete always automatically*.  how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Ensure ‘Lock Icons’ in your settings is *off*:

[image]
(at bottom right)

#### 2. Ensure your `<Application>.dockitem` (whereever you prepare it before copying) is pointing to a `.desktop` file contains at least a minimal set like so:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/someApp -someParameter
Name=My Fancy App
Icon=/home/jacob/Thema/icon/ubu.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=False
```

*These are the two most common issues to the best of my knowledge. Then, copying over (or: dragging in) should work.*

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following command:

```
plank --preferences
```

Then go to the Behavior tab, see switcher button below, turn off lock icon

It worked for me.